# C# Creating a Class List<>/Dictionary<>, writing to and reading from .txt file as a database without overwriting data

Tags: c#, list, file, keychain

This is one of the most common questions you guys get here so forgive me but I cannot get past this no matter how hard I search.

I am building a keychain application for a project in Windows Forms Application, and for the purpose of understanding this concept as easily as possible I went with a List<> rather than Dictionary//iList

This is the Class I have been using:

```
public class Account
{
    public static List<Account> myAccountList = new List<Account>();
    public string Domain; //this is supposed to be google/skype/facebook
    public string Email;
    public string Username;
    public string Password;

    public Account (string domain, string email, string username, string password)
    {
        Domain = domain;
        Email = email;
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        myAccountList.Add(new Account(domain, email, username, password)); //constructor calls the new list instance
    }
    private static void SaveToFile()
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@accountdb.txt, myAccountList);
    }
    private static void ReadFromFile() // this is meant to be used as authentication in my main form, it isn't necessary right now..
    {
        System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@accountdb.txt);
    }
}
```

I have a couple issues with this:

1. I cannot create a functional Save method to write to file, I have tried several methods in `System.IO`
2. When I changed the list to a one-dimensional array, it would constantly overwrite it, I want to simulate MySQL to familiarize myself for later on.

The Button Click event that calls the Constructor:

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string domain, email, username, password;
        domain = comboboxDomain.Text;
        email = textboxEmail.Text;
        username = textboxUsername.Text;
        password = textboxPassword.Text;
        //Checking for correct EMAIL

        if (!textboxEmail.Text.Contains("@") && (!textboxEmail.Text.Contains(".")))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email Format");
        }
        else
        {
            Account account = new Account(domain, email, username, password);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Comment: @maccettura I want to know what is wrong with the way I am writing the list to file, and how to prevent the save method from overwriting previous credentials in the .txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WriteAllLines` expects an `string[]` as the second parameter.  So you need to create a way to represent a single `Account` object as a string.  The easiest way is to override the `ToString` method.  Then use the Linq `Select` method to select them.

Also, it would be better if the `Account` class did not also contain the list of accounts.  That should really be a separate class.  Try something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var accountList = new AccountList();

    //Save a few accounts to the file
    Account a1 = new Account("Google", "GoogleEmail", "GoogleUser", "GooglePass");
    accountList.Add(a1);
    Account a2 = new Account("Netflix", "NetflixEmail", "NetflixUser", "NetflixPass");
    accountList.Add(a2);

    AccountList.SaveToFile(@"g:\test\accounts.txt", accountList);


    //Load the accounts from the file
    AccountList aList2 = AccountList.ReadFromFile(@"g:\test\accounts.txt");
    aList2.Dump();
}

public class AccountList
{
    private List<Account> accounts;
    public IEnumerable<Account> Accounts { get { return accounts;} }

    public AccountList()
    {
        this.accounts = new List<Account>();
    }

    public void Add(Account a)
    {
        accounts.Add(a);
    }

    public static void SaveToFile(string filename, AccountList accounts)
    {
        //Selects all the `Account` instances and creates a string[]
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, accounts.Accounts.Select(a => $"{a}").ToArray());
    }

    public static AccountList ReadFromFile(string filename) // this is meant to be used as authentication in my main form, it isn't necessary right now..
    {
        var result = new AccountList();

        //Read each line from the file and create an Account instance.
        foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                var parts = line.Split(',');
                if (parts.Length == 4)
                {
                    Account a = new Account(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
                    result.Add(a);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public string Domain; //this is supposed to be google/skype/facebook
    public string Email;
    public string Username;
    public string Password;

    public Account(string domain, string email, string username, string password)
    {
        Domain = domain;
        Email = email;
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Domain},{Email},{Username},{Password}";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly advanced for my current understanding but I have no doubt that it would help others so I will mark it as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, it sounds like you want to *append* and not *write*. If you want to append to a file (i.e add to whats already there) you need to use the `AppendAllLines()` function.

However you have bigger issues because you are trying to write a List of objects, not strings to your file.  If you want to just write the passwords, you need this:

```
private static void SaveToFile()
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllLines("path/to/file", myAccountList.Select(x => x.Password));
}
```

This method will append to a file if it exists, if it does not exist it just creates a new file.

Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @S.Nog I updated my answer, I did not notice you were trying to write a `IEnumerable<Account>` to a file.  I assumed _your_ code compiled.

Comment: It seems like this creates the .txt file but it does not actually write the `Password` string to the file. And yes, it did not compile from the beginning I should have clarified that.

Comment: Are you sure `myAccountList` has items with `Password`'s that are not empty?  Step through on the debugger

Comment: Is it possible that I am introducing the list incorrectly? It works perfectly if I switch it from a list to array, but the goal here was to familiarize myself with list as well. I am going through the debugger now